# jQuery plugin: prevent multiply calls of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Recently, I'm writing a jQuery plugin which moves html elements.
My plugin is something like this:

```
$('#div1').moveIt({ top: 100, left: 200 });
```

The problem is, When I call `moveIt` more than once for an element. It does all methods together. something like this:

```
$('#div1').moveIt({ top: 100, left: 200 }); // first call
$('#div1').moveIt({ top: 200, left: 300 }); // second call
// even more calls ....
```

The questions are:

1. How can I prevent the the second call inside my plugin?
2. How can I overwrite the new values of second call into the first call?

A simple sample code will be enough.

edit: [**here is my problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/jHzLN/)

Comment: Can you explain what your plugin does? If it just sets the CSS properties, then the last call will be the one that determines the values. If it's animation, the animations should chain automatically.

Comment: @acbabis Check out the edit. I added a jsFiddle. As you can see the issue, Both methods create a `setTimeout` for the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were going for? http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/B89Bx/. Let me know:

```
$(function()
{
    var methods = 
    {
        init : function(options)  {
            $(this).each(function() {
                var self = $(this);
                var settings = $.extend({
                    top      : 50,
                    left     : 50,
                    dir      : true,
                }, options);
                var i=0, j=0;
                var move = function()
                {
                    settings = self.data('moveItTarget');
                    if(settings.dir)
                    {
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i+=10;
                        j+=10; 
                    }

                    self.css({'top':Math.min(i, settings.top),
                            'left':Math.min(j, settings.left)});

                    if(j<=settings.top && i<=settings.top)
                    {
                        setTimeout(move,1);  
                    } else {
                        self.data('movingIt', false);
                    }
                };
                self.data('moveItTarget', settings);
                if(!self.data('movingIt')) {
                    self.data('movingIt', true);
                    move();                    
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.moveIt = function(methodOrOptions) {
        if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
            return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this,
                    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions==='object' || !methodOrOptions) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method "'+methodOrOptions+'" does not exist!');
        }    
    };
}(jQuery));
$('#div1').moveIt({ top: 100, left: 100,  dir: true }); // first call
$('#div1').moveIt({ top: 300, left: 300,  dir: false }); // second call
```

Comment: I'm kind of busy right now, I'll test it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: That can work to. either store last directions or store timeout object and reset it. both will do.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**: What about your problem - check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/jHzLN/1/

You have to save timeout and clear it when you set new one.

What you are asking for is called throttle.
Check this article http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

But as you are really using jquery animations ( your plugin name tells that ), you have to use something else.

Check [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method

```
 $(selector).stop(true, true).animate(...)
```

Another interesting thing you can do is queue additional animations. Use `queue:true` option for that:

```
$(selector).animate({ left:...} , { queue: true })
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's more complex than `animate()` and using `stop`. The above code is just a sample code to show my question concept.

Comment: @vittore Thanks but I think that is not my problem.

Comment: @vittore check out jsFiddle. My code is something like that.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M check updated answer, it is much simplier that you think.